# How to cross-compile vsomeip for android. boost filesystem error

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm doing cross-compile vsomeip for android. But, I have fatal error to boost library. I already to boost for android. It doesn't have error. But, In vsomeip for android, I have boost error.

```
[ 61%] Linking CXX executable vsomeipd
../libvsomeip.so.2.0.1: error: undefined reference to 
'boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
../libvsomeip.so.2.0.1: error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../libvsomeip.so.2.0.1: error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../libvsomeip.so.2.0.1: error: undefined reference to ' 
'boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
clang50++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: [daemon/vsomeipd] Error 1
make[1]: [daemon/CMakeFiles/vsomeipd.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[98%] Built target vsomeip-sd
make: [all] Error 2
```

I'm using clang++ in Android-ndk-16b,14b.
please help me.....

Comment: Are you linking Boost as a shared object or as a static library?  Are you creating libvsomeip.so.2.0.1 with this link, or is it the executable?  What is the actual command line that is being used to invoke the linker?  (Please [edit] your question with all the answers to these questions.)

Comment: I wonder, how you resolved **shm_open()** and her kin.